# ETE2 - One Child Node with Multiple Parents?

Tags: python, tree, phylogeny, etetoolkit

I'm trying to create a tree using the ETE2 module in Python. I'd like to add 1 child node to 2 parent nodes so that they both connect to the child when the tree is displayed. I'm a complete novice with ETE, so please forgive me if this is an easy question.
Code:

```
from ete2 import Tree, TreeNode, TextFace


classes = Tree()

#adding 1
course1 = TreeNode(name="Course 1")
face1 = TextFace(text="Course 1")
course1.add_face(face1, column=1)
classes.add_child(child=course1)

#adding 2
course2 = TreeNode(name="Course 2")
face2 = TextFace(text="Course 2")
course2.add_face(face2, column=1)
course1.add_child(child=course2)

#adding 3
course3 = TreeNode(name="Course 3")
face3 = TextFace(text="Course 3")
course3.add_face(face3, column=1)
#adding course3 to 2 parents
course1.add_child(child=course3)
course2.add_child(child=course3)

classes.show()
```

Output is [image: here]

Am I fundamentally going against the idea of a tree here? Does ETE have a simple(r) way to do what I'm proposing?

Let me know if you need more info to help.

Comment: `Am I fundamentally going against the idea of a tree here`: yes. What you want is *not* a tree. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure) for a tree definition.

Comment: @boardrider So what structure should I be using?

Comment: You can use the structure you use now, just don't call it a `tree.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I essentially figured out the answer to my own question: the data structure I should be using is not a tree. @boardrider pointed out that a tree inherently is a "one to many" structure, mapping one parent node to one or more children.

The solution was a **Directed Acyclic Graph**. This is a variation of a graph data structure, which maps "many to many" to continue with the phrasing from above.

Resources:

[Graph data structure basics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2guA5uMEmZQ)

[Python specific graph structures](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Graphs/graphintro.html)

I will edit this as I progress.